# Where can I Find the Memory map and register table for the S70FL01GS

Tags: datasheet, memory, flash, interface

I am currently working with this device:

https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/100/001-98295_S70FL01GS_1_Gbit_128_Mbyte_3.0V_SPI_Flas-1102682.pdf

The datasheet provides some high-level details about this flash memory device, but it doesn't show me the memory map, the register table, or how exactly I can store/load values in this flash mem. I was wondering if there was a separate document for the more detailed stuff.

Answer (score 0):

On page 14 of the linked datasheet you will find links for additional information, including application notes and software.

This product comprises two die of a different part number, S25FL512S, so you should also look for documentation on that device. At the bottom of page 1 of your datasheet you will find a link to the datasheet for this part number. All you need to do is click.